# Stop and play audio with only one button

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have one button that plays audio and also stops it.  If I tap the button **before** the completion of the MP3 audio, it stops the audio.  I then tap it a second time, and the audio plays again from the beginning.  This is fine.

The Problem is:

If I tap the button **after** the audio finishes playing the MP3, nothing happens.  It should play the audio.  If I tap the button a second time, it does play the audio.

How can I make it play when the audio has finished playing with single tap?

I have a flag setup to detect if the audio is playing.  I think this is the problem.

```
switch playingFlag

        {

        case true:
            duaPlayer?.stop()

            playingFlag = false
        case false: 

            setUpAudio()
            play()
            playingFlag = true }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post the parts of your code where you play and stop the audio, and probably where you initialize the audio file.

Comment: You could start by showing some code. Since you haven't, we can't help you.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are stuck?

Comment: I think I need to set a flag that indicates that the audio played successfully until the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set something up like this, to test if the player is actually playing or not.  Currently, the flag is not being triggered when the player stops, so when you push the button the first time, the boolean changes to false and then plays on the second click.

Maybe this will work for you.

```
switch duaPlayer.playing
{
case true:
    duaPlayer.stop()
case false:
    setUpAudio()
    play()
}
```

Let me know.